# Generic factory method and type inference

Tags: swift, generics

I have the following class with a generic factory method:

```
final class Something<T> {
    
    let value: T
    
    init(initial: T) {
        value = initial
    }
    
}

extension Something {
    
    class func zip<A, B>(_ a: A, _ b: B) -> Something<(A, B)> {
        let initial = (a, b)
        return Something<(A, B)>(initial: initial)
    }
    
}
```

How come I can’t call `zip` without explicitly specifying the return type?

```
// ERROR: Cannot invoke `zip` with an argument list of type `(Int, Int)`
let y = Something.zip(1, 2)

// OK: Works but it’s unacceptable to require this on caller's side
let x = Something<(Int, Int)>.zip(1, 2)
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think you will always have to specify the type somewhere. That's how generics work.

Comment: @Sulthan Yeah, as soon as there's `T` in the signature, everything works. I though the compiler would figure out such a simple use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this is that there's nothing in this call:

```
let y = Something.zip(1, 2)
```

That tells Swift what `T` should be.

Your call implicitly specifies what `A` and `B` should be, and specifies the method should return `Something<A, B>`. But that `Something<A, B>` is not connected to `Something<T>`.

In fact, nothing at all in your call is connected to `T`; `T` is left unspecified, so it could be anything. I mean that literally—you can actually put (nearly) any random type in the angle brackets after `Something` and it'll work exactly the same:

```
let y = Something<UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>.zip(1, 2)
```

What you would really like to do is somehow specify that `T` has to be a tuple and the two parameters are of the same types as the tuple's elements. Unfortunately, Swift doesn't currently have the features needed to properly do that. If the language were more sophisticated, you could say something like this:

```
extension<A, B> Something where T == (A, B) {
    class func zip(a: A, _ b: B) -> Something {
        let initial = (a, b)
        return Something(initial: initial)
    }
}
```

But for now, you'll have to make do with this horrible hack, which works by meaninglessly reusing the `T` type parameter so that it's no longer at loose ends:

```
extension Something {
    class func zip<B>(a: T, _ b: B) -> Something<(T, B)> {
        let initial = (a, b)
        return Something<(T, B)>(initial: initial)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short explanation, you use generics not correct. It's not realtime feature, it's precompile thing. If you need to make abstract class from generic input values, see and do like this:

```
class Abstract<T> {
    init(value: T) {
        print("inputed value: \(value)")
    }
}

class Something {
    class func zip<A, B>(value: A, value2: B) -> Abstract<(A, B)> {
        print("Something.zip", value, value2)

        return Abstract<(A, B)>(value: (value, value2))
    }
}

Something.zip(5, value2: 40) // "inputed value: (5, 40)"
```

Comment: But for that, you need to have an instance of `Something` before you call `zip`. I wanted to have a zip factory, e.g. either `init` or a `static` function.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic use `class func` for this, if you need class factory.

Comment: Yeah, that works. In that case, I would rather make it a free function but I wanted to avoid that. Do you have any idea _why_ it doesn't work on a generic class?

Comment: Yes, but don't have time for explanation. Tip: read generics vs protocols, and you will find difference. Btw, thanks for downvote :DD

Comment: Sorry. After your edits, it's an upvote from me. However, I can't accept the answer yet because it doesn't explain _why_ this happens in a generic class.

Answer (score 0):

`T` simply isn't related to `A` and `B` in that way and so can't be inferred.

Eg.

```
let z = Something<(String, String)>.zip(1, 2)
let z2 = Something<AnyObject>.zip(1, 2)
```

work just fine to return a `Something<(Int, Int)>`

Comment: Works fine but requiring this on caller's side is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce type inference for your case like this:

```
final class Something<T> {

    let value: T

    init(initial: T) {
        value = initial
    }

    class func zip<A, B>(_ a: A, _ b: B)  ->  Something<T> where T == (A, B) {
        let initial = (a, b)
        return Something<(A, B)>(initial: initial)
    }

}

let y = Something.zip(1, 2) //works
```